# Raid 10, Logical device are missing

Tags: raid, adaptec

I have a problem with a RAID 10, I have 4 disks on raid. A disc has just been changed (0,3). But I can not rebuild the array. Logical device are setted as "Missing".

All commands return to me the following error

```
/usr/StorMan# /usr/StorMan/arcconf setstate 1 device 0 3 rdyControllers found: 1
The device specified does not exist.

Command aborted.
```

```
/usr/StorMan# /usr/StorMan/arcconf getconfig 1 
Controllers found: 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Controller information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Controller Status                        : Optimal
   Channel description                      : SAS/SATA
   Controller Model                         : Adaptec 2405
   Controller Serial Number                 : 2D2711FE327
   Physical Slot                            : 16
   Temperature                              : 68 C/ 154 F (Normal)
   Installed memory                         : 128 MB
   Copyback                                 : Disabled
   Background consistency check             : Disabled
   Automatic Failover                       : Enabled
   Global task priority                     : High
   Performance Mode                         : Default/Dynamic
   Stayawake period                         : Disabled
   Spinup limit internal drives             : 0
   Spinup limit external drives             : 0
   Defunct disk drive count                 : 0
   Logical devices/Failed/Degraded          : 1/0/1
   SSDs assigned to MaxIQ Cache pool        : 0
   Maximum SSDs allowed in MaxIQ Cache pool : 8
   MaxIQ Read Cache Pool Size               : 0.000 GB
   MaxIQ cache fetch rate                   : 0
   MaxIQ Cache Read, Write Balance Factor   : 3,1
   NCQ status                               : Enabled
   Statistics data collection mode          : Enabled
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Controller Version Information
   --------------------------------------------------------
   BIOS                                     : 5.2-0 (18937)
   Firmware                                 : 5.2-0 (18937)
   Driver                                   : 1.1-7 (28000)
   Boot Flash                               : 5.2-0 (18937)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Logical device information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Logical device number 0
   Logical device name                      : 
   RAID level                               : 10
   Status of logical device                 : Degraded
   Size                                     : 3809270 MB
   Stripe-unit size                         : 256 KB
   Read-cache mode                          : Enabled
   MaxIQ preferred cache setting            : Enabled
   MaxIQ cache setting                      : Disabled
   Write-cache mode                         : Enabled (write-back)
   Write-cache setting                      : Enabled (write-back)
   Partitioned                              : Yes
   Protected by Hot-Spare                   : No
   Bootable                                 : Yes
   Failed stripes                           : Yes
   Power settings                           : Disabled
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Logical device segment information
   --------------------------------------------------------
   Group 0, Segment 0                       : Present (0,1)             W1F20KQ9
   Group 0, Segment 1                       : Present (0,0)             Z34063KS
   Group 1, Segment 0                       : Present (0,2)             W1E2PW1C
   Group 1, Segment 1                       : Missing


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Physical Device information
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      Device #0
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 3.0 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,0(0:0)
         Reported Location                  : Connector 0, Device 0
         Vendor                             : 
         Model                              : ST2000DM001-1CH1
         Firmware                           : CC24
         Serial number                      : Z34063KS
         Size                               : 1907729 MB
         Write Cache                        : Enabled (write-back)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         Power State                        : Full rpm
         Supported Power States             : Full rpm,Powered off,Reduced rpm
         SSD                                : No
         MaxIQ Cache Capable                : No
         MaxIQ Cache Assigned               : No
         NCQ status                         : Enabled
      Device #1
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 3.0 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,1(1:0)
         Reported Location                  : Connector 0, Device 1
         Vendor                             : 
         Model                              : ST2000DM001-1CH1
         Firmware                           : CC24
         Serial number                      : W1F20KQ9
         Size                               : 1907729 MB
         Write Cache                        : Enabled (write-back)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         Power State                        : Full rpm
         Supported Power States             : Full rpm,Powered off,Reduced rpm
         SSD                                : No
         MaxIQ Cache Capable                : No
         MaxIQ Cache Assigned               : No
         NCQ status                         : Enabled
      Device #2
         Device is a Hard drive
         State                              : Online
         Supported                          : Yes
         Transfer Speed                     : SATA 3.0 Gb/s
         Reported Channel,Device(T:L)       : 0,2(2:0)
         Reported Location                  : Connector 0, Device 2
         Vendor                             : 
         Model                              : ST2000DM001-1CH1
         Firmware                           : CC24
         Serial number                      : W1E2PW1C
         Size                               : 1907729 MB
         Write Cache                        : Enabled (write-back)
         FRU                                : None
         S.M.A.R.T.                         : No
         S.M.A.R.T. warnings                : 0
         Power State                        : Full rpm
         Supported Power States             : Full rpm,Powered off,Reduced rpm
         SSD                                : No
         MaxIQ Cache Capable                : No
         MaxIQ Cache Assigned               : No
         NCQ status                         : Enabled
```

How can I start the rebuilding of the array?

Comment: Adaptec controller, eh?  My condolences, and good luck with that.  I lost a very large array thanks to an Adaptec controller crapping out for no ostensible reason... might want to think about switching to an LSI card.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and had to put the new disk in the HSP (Hot Spare) state first. After that, with failover set to on, the rebuild process was started automatically.

```
/usr/StorMan/arcconf setstate 1 DEVICE 0 26 HSP
```

Be sure that you have the corresponding IDs, channel-IDs, etc.

```
/usr/StorMan/arcconf getconfig 1 ld 1 | grep Rebuild
   Segment 6 : Rebuilding (Controller:1,Enclosure:0,Slot:18) Z1P5PETG
```

Answer (score 0):

Get into the Controller's BIOS, select the degraded array and press CTRL+R to rebuild the array.